# How can ı remove ant design's space between dropdown and menu?

Tags: css, antd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcr1E.png)

Hello, I want to delete the space between the menu and the button, so the button and the drop-down menu will be combined. I don't know how to do this can you help me?
I can not find how can ı remove it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by wrapping the `Button` inside a `span` element. like this:

```
 <Dropdown placement="bottomLeft" ...>
  <span>
    <Button>bottomLeft</Button>
  </span>
</Dropdown>
```

it works because `Dropdown` will calculate it's popup position based on the top of the element which placed directly inside the `<Dropdown>`, and since in the above solution, span has y-overflow, so the the popup will be shown without any space between `Button` and popup. You can controll the space between popup and `Button` by styling the `span` element like this:

```
 <Dropdown placement="bottomCenter" ...>
   <span style={{ display: 'inline-block', height: 27 }}>
     <Button>bottomCenter</Button>
  </span>
 </Dropdown>
```

I've implemented an example [Here on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4e1der) you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better way for us to help you if you share the code you wrote here.